# ios - Setting value in to FIRDataSnapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to swift and having trouble with setting value to FIRDataSnapshot. I simply created a calculator. I took MealCaloryArray in didload method and display it tableviewcell (with the help of FIRDataSnapshot list) and the calory is changed in the plus function and I have to send the new value to tableviewcell again. However, I couldnt set the new value in FIRDataSnapshot array list. I tried to use`self.calory[buttonRow].setValue(<value: n, forUndefinedKey:"")`but I dont have proper "forUndefinedKey" value. Do you have any suggestions?

My nested Firebase DB Structure and code blocks is attached.

Firebase Child Structure:

[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0quKz.png)

```
var calory: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let CoursesRef = ref.child("CompanyMeals")

CoursesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

self.calory = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "MealCaloryArray").children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
self.calory.append(snapshot)
self.ingredientTableView.reloadData()
})
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = ingredientTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MealCalculatorListCell
let cellcalory = self.calory[indexPath.row].value as? Double

if (cellcalory != nil) {
cell.itemTotalCalory.text = ("\(cellcalory!)")//String (describing: cellcalory)
let cellcalory1 = Int(cellcalory!)
firstCaloriesArray.append((cellcalory1 as AnyObject))
}
}

@IBAction func plusAction(sender: UIButton) {

cell.itemTotalCalory.text = String ((Int(oldcalory!) + fcCalory))
let newcalory = cell.itemTotalCalory.text
let n = String(newcalory!)
self.calory[buttonRow].setValue(value: n, forUndefinedKey: "")
}
```

Comment: Your should really create a class or struct, populate that with the data from the snapshot and store that object in the array. It will be much easier to deal with; adding, editing, removing, searching, sorting etc. It's just a thought.

Comment: @Jay thanks for your reply, is the modifying - self.calory[buttonRow].setValue(value: n, forUndefinedKey: "") - line a bad idea for this issue? :/